# Generar un documento Word con base en un .php y consultar

Tags: mysql, html5, css3, php7, phpword

compañeros,

Estoy realizando un sistema que me registra ingresos y salidas de unos estudiantes y que me genera un reporte de los que llegaron tarde. Para delimitar las páginas del documento, hago una consulta en el .php que será convertido.

Aquí el HTML5 y el JavaScript de la primera página:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enviar").click(function( event ) {
            /*Con esto evitamos que se recargue la página.*/
            event.preventDefault();
            var data=$("form").serialize(); 
            $.ajax({                        
                method:"POST",                 
                url:"consultar_fecha.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#consulta').html(data);          
                }
            });
        })
        $("#ext").click(function( event ) {
            /*Con esto evitamos que se recargue la página.*/
            event.preventDefault();
            var data=$("form").serialize();
            $.ajax({                        
                method:"POST",                 
                url:"reportes.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);  
                }
            });
        })
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<font class="mensajes" id="desde">Desde: </font>
<font class="mensaje" id="hasta">Hasta: </font>
<font class="mensaje" id="exportar">Exportar con el nombre: </font>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <input type="date" name="inicio" id="inicio" class='input'>
    <input type="date" name="final" id="final" class='input'>
    <button type="submit" id="enviar">Consultar</button>
</form>
<button id="ext"><a href="reportes.php">Exportar</a></button>
<section id="consulta">
</section>
```

Al hacer click en el botón con id="ext", me debería descargar un documento en word con esta información:

```
$final=$_POST['final'];
$n=str_replace(" ", "_", "$nombre");
include('conexion.php');
require_once("../dompdf-0.5.1/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$reporte=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM novedades, aprendices, fichas WHERE fecha_novedad BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$final' AND novedades.doc_ap=aprendices.doc_ap AND aprendices.id_ficha=fichas.id_ficha");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $n . ".doc");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<head>
    <title>Reporte Aprendices.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .especial{
            text-align:center;
        }
        body{
            width:60%;
            margin:auto;
        }
        .firma{
            text-align:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($reporte)) {
    ?>
    <p><center>25-9511-2</center></p>
    <p><center>Girardot,</center></p>
    <br>
    <br>
<?php
if ($r['genero_ap']=='lo') {
    echo "Señor, <br>";
    echo $r['nombres_ap'] . " " . $r['apellidos_ap'] . "<br>";
    echo $r['tipo_doc_ap'] . " " . $r['doc_ap'] . "<br>";
    echo "Aprendiz del " . $r['nivel_ficha'] . " en " . $r['nombre_ficha'] . "<br>";
    echo "Ficha: " . $r['id_ficha'] . "<br>";
    echo "Centro de la Tecnología del Diseño y la Productividad Empresarial. <br>";
    echo "Girardot. <br><br><br>";
    echo "<p align='right'><strong>Asunto: Llamado de Atención por incumplimiento horario de ingreso a la formación.</strong></p><br><br>";
    echo "<font align='justify'><p>Cordial saludo, señor " . $r['nombres_ap'] . ":</p>";
    echo "<p>En atención a que en la fecha usted se presentó al Centro de Formación en un horario que supera la franja asignada para el ingreso a la capacitación que diariamente recibe en el Sena; de manera comedida procedemos a formularle el presente LLAMADO DE ATENCION, teniendo en cuenta que con su actitud usted está faltando al numeral 1 del Artículo 9 del Capítulo III del Reglamento del Aprendiz del Sena, Acuerdo 0007 de 2012, que al tenor dice:</p>";
    echo "<p class='especial'><i>“1. Cumplir con todas las actividades propias de su proceso de aprendizaje o del plan de mejoramiento, definidas durante su etapa lectiva y productiva.”</i></p>";
    echo "<p>En consideración a lo manifestado, " . $r['genero_ap'] . " invitamos a mejorar los hechos que conllevan el retardo en la asistencia a los compromisos, teniendo en cuenta que la reiteración de las faltas implica aplicar lo dispuesto en el citado Reglamento.</p>";
    echo "<br><br><p>Antentamente, </p><br><br><br>";
    echo "<p class='firma'><br>Persona x<br>";
    echo "Coordinador de Formación Profesional, Gestión Educativa y Relaciones Coorporativas.<br><br><br></p>";
    echo "</font>";
}else{
    echo "Señorita, <br>";
    echo $r['nombres_ap'] . " " . $r['apellidos_ap'] . "<br>";
    echo $r['tipo_doc_ap'] . " " . $r['doc_ap'] . "<br>";
    echo "Aprendiz del " . $r['nivel_ficha'] . " en " . $r['nombre_ficha'] . "<br>";
    echo "Ficha: " . $r['id_ficha'] . "<br>";
    echo "Centro de la Tecnología del Diseño y la Productividad Empresarial. <br>";
    echo "Girardot. <br><br><br>";
    echo "<p align='right'><strong>Asunto: Llamado de Atención por incumplimiento horario de ingreso a la formación.</strong></p><br><br>.";
    echo "<font align='justify'><p>Cordial saludo, señorita " . $r['nombres_ap'] . ":</p>";
    echo "<p>En atención a que en la fecha usted se presentó al Centro de Formación en un horario que supera la franja asignada para el ingreso a la capacitación que diariamente recibe en el Sena; de manera comedida procedemos a formularle el presente LLAMADO DE ATENCION, teniendo en cuenta que con su actitud usted está faltando al numeral 1 del Artículo 9 del Capítulo III del Reglamento del Aprendiz del Sena, Acuerdo 0007 de 2012, que al tenor dice:</p>";
    echo "<p class='especial'><i>“1. Cumplir con todas las actividades propias de su proceso de aprendizaje o del plan de mejoramiento, definidas durante su etapa lectiva y productiva.”</i></p>";
    echo "<p>En consideración a lo manifestado, " . $r['genero_ap'] . " invitamos a mejorar los hechos que conllevan el retardo en la asistencia a los compromisos, teniendo en cuenta que la reiteración de las faltas implica aplicar lo dispuesto en el citado Reglamento.</p>";
    echo "<br><br><p>Antentamente, </p><br><br><br>";
    echo "<p class='firma'><br>Persona x<br>";
    echo "Coordinador de Formación Profesional, Gestión Educativa y Relaciones Coorporativas.<br><br><br></p>";
    echo "</font>";
}
}
?>
```

Necesito que se me genere un documento con esa información y seguir delimitándolo con las consultas.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Santiago, pero cuál es el problema que estás obteniendo? y deberías de generar un reporte en archivos PDF; es lo sugerido.

Comment: El problema es que al darle click a ext, no me descarga el documento, me toca abrirlo en una nueva pestaña; al hacerlo, me descargar un documento en blanco. 
¿Podrías ayudarme, por favor?

Comment: Dejame redacto muy bien la respuesta, lo voy a hacer con PDF, porque la verdad no he trabajado con WORD aunque en teoría debería ser igual (Solo cambiaria el uso de la librería que tengas a tu disposición)